# How to check and delete duplicates values in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, duplicates

I have a database on Firebase and a tableview.
I have a list of brands, models, and year for motorcycles and I want to retrieve the list of brands on the tableview.

The problem is the DB has duplicates values. There is more than one motorcycle from Suzuki, there is more one models of SV 650, etc.

How can I check duplicates values, put it in a new array, and retrieve it in the tableview?

This is my TableViewController file:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class SelectionMarqueViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        loadMarques()
    }

    func loadMarques() {
        var ref : DatabaseReference?
        ref = Database.database(url: "https://myride-test.firebaseio.com/").reference()
        ref?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let MarqueText = dict["Marque"] as! String
                let post = Post(MarqueText: MarqueText)
                self.posts.append(post)
                print(self.posts)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].Marque
        return cell
    }
}
```

And this one is the file with the Post func:

```
import Foundation

class Post {
    var Marque: String

    init(MarqueText: String) {
        Marque = MarqueText
    }
}
```

Here my Firebase Database:

[image: https://ibb.co/X5fwyqK]

Actually the tableview shows the complete list of brands in the DB, and so, many times the same brands.

On the DB and code:
"Marque" correspond to the brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `Hashable`

```
class Post : Hashable {
    var marque: String

    init(marqueText: String) {
        marque = marqueText
    }
    // Equatable for contains
    static func == (lhs:Post,rhs:Post) -> Bool {
      return lhs.marque == rhs.marque
    }
   // Hashable for Set
   var hashValue:Int {
    return marque.hashValue
   }

}
```

and use

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
   let MarqueText = dict["Marque"] as! String
   let post = Post(MarqueText: MarqueText)
   self.posts.append(post)
   self.posts = Array(Set(self.posts))
   print(self.posts)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Or simply

```
let marqueText = dict["Marque"] as! String 
if !self.posts.map { $0.marqueText}.contains(marqueText) {
   let post = Post(marqueText:marqueText)
   self.posts.append(post)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You should never assume that two items with the same hash value are equal. I guess it is always better to implement a Diffable protocol.

Comment: **You should never assume that two items with the same hash value are equal**  How and Why ?? **Diffable** it's swift not java

Comment: If you consider how hashable checks if two items are the same is by doing a XOR operator. But XOR is commutative (A ^ B) = (B ^ A). If two instances A and B of the same type, if a == b, then a.hashValue == b.hashValue. The reverse is not true: Two instances with equal hash values are not necessarily equal to each other. Diffable can be implemented. It's not swift standard but can be done for better permormance.

Comment: i didn't use xor here plus order is preserved a-b will always a-b not b-a   , also right check this https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-hashable/

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work. I'm just saying that at some point it might happen. I actually have experienced it. `Hashable` in two of my projects was not enough to compare items. So, most of the time yes, but maybe not always. In those two cases I implemented something similar to: https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery/blob/master/SourceryRuntime/Sources/Diffable.swift and everything worked better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand where to place it in my code.
When I place it like that it didn't work: 
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any], !self.posts.map { snapshot.marqueText}.contains(marqueText) {

Xcode says Cannot convert value of type '((Post) throws -> _) throws -> [_]' to expected argument type 'Bool' and Use of unresolved identifier 'marqueText'

Comment: Another error Cannot assign value of type 'Set<Post>' to type '[Post]'

Answer (score 0):

Check and append if the marque is not available in the datasource of the tableview.

```
func appendMarqueAndReloadIfNeeded(_ marque: String) {
  if self.posts.map({ $0.Marque }).contains(marque) {
    // Do nothing
  } else {
    self.posts.append(Post(MarqueText: marque))
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Then you call it inside `observe`:

```
///....
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
  let MarqueText = dict["Marque"] as! String
  self.appendMarqueAndReloadIfNeeded(MarqueText)
}
///....
```

Comment: if self.posts.map({ $0.Marque }).contains(marque) { return error Unable to infer closure type in the current context

Comment: you can bring it out of the IF statement: `let marques = self.posts.map({ $0.Marque }); if marques.contains(marque) { ... }`